# Convert string coming from web service to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a connection to remote DB and I have get some statistical data from the DB. So I have decided to create a web service and get the desired data through it. DB server is SQL Server on Windows and I need to display data in my PHP web page.

First I have written the web service which returns string like

```
"[
  { 
    "name" : "John", 
    "Age":"54"
  }, 
  {
    "name":"Jack",
    "Age":"33"
  }
 ]"
```

I have got that string using PHP's file_get_contents() method.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://myurl.org/services.asmx/namelistJson');
```

But there are some unwanted tags return, in the beginning

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://myurl.org/services.asmx?op=namelistJson">
```

in at the end

```
</string>
```

I clean them using

```
$json = strip_tags(file_get_contents('http://myurl.org/services.asmx/namelistJson'));
```

Now I have a json string.

I want to use this string as JSON for javascript in order to create a table.

```
<?php

$json = strip_tags(file_get_contents('http://myurl.org/services.asmx/namelistJson'));

?>
<script>

    var response = $.parse(<?php echo $json; ?>);

    $.each(response, function(i, item) {
        $('<tr>')
                .html("<td>" + response[i].name + "</td>"
                        + "<td>" + response[i].Age + "</td>"
                        )
                .appendTo('#nameList');
    });

</script>

?>
<table id="nameList" class="table">
</table>
```

I am getting error about missing `]` symbol. FireBug says that

> SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

How can I convert string to json properly in order to use it on javascript?

**EDIT:**

If I modify the line

```
var response = $.parse(<?php echo $json; ?>);
```

to

```
var response = <?php echo $json; ?>;
```

I get `]` error still.

HTML output is as the following:

```
<script>

...

var response = [{"name" : "John",  "Age" : "14"},  {"name" : "40"}, ... ];

...

</script>
```

Comment: JSON is valid JavaScript syntax, so you can just drop the string directly into JavaScript code. There's no need to explicitly parse it with a function call.

Comment: Well, is the final `]` missing?  Do a view source on your rendered php page and check.

Comment: Can you show the HTML and Javascript as they appear when you View Source in the browser? I mean paste in *exactly* what `var response = <?php echo $json; ?>;` expands to.

Comment: @James, no it is not. It is there.

Comment: Well something is wrong with the object's syntax.  Take the whole response from `[` to `]` and validate it with [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: If you are getting json data from the server you have convert it like this                                                                var response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(<?php echo $json; ?>));

Comment: I have found the problem. Sorry for wasting your time. The list is very long and I accidently add a closing curly brace before the last element.

I will delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a string and then again convert it to json object, you can directly send json object from webservice and directly use it in the scripts(jquery) as below:

Below is the code in my webservice

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
public static object GetGridData() 
{
    DataTable dt = GetRecords(); // Fetch the data from sql in form of a datatable
    var returnData = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     select new
                     {
                        Id = row["Id"]  // Here the Id in row["Id"] specifies the column in database
                         name = row["name"],
                         age = row["age"]
                     };
    return returnData;
}
```

To access it as object in jquery, use the below code:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'url of webservice along with method', 
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
                tyep: 'GET',
                success: function (datas) {
                    var data = datas.d;
                        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        $('<tr>').html("<td>" + value.name + "</td>"+ "<td>" + value.Age + "</td>"
                    ).appendTo('#nameList');
                        });
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('error occured');
                }
            });
```

But if you really want to send it using string and parsing it into json then you can use

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
```

or else you can verify if your json string is valid or not by just pasting your json string in [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is really useful for me. Prevents syntax errors like I have made.